# how to wait on a cancellation token AND an EventWaitHandle at the same time, in F#?

Tags: f#, cancellationtokensource, waithandle

I would like to find a way to combine these two lines:

```
cancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne() |> ignore
waitHandle.WaitOne() |> ignore
```

whichever happens first would let the execution flow continue. Can this be done?

Comment: What problem did you have with the solution from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637876/cancellation-token-in-f-threads)?

Comment: None, it was exactly what I was looking for. When I faced the problem I looked at it from different perspectives and didn’t realize it was the same thing. I think we can safely close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you could put the the two handles in an array and then wait on it. Something like:

```
[|
    cancellationToken.WaitHandle
    waitHandle
|] |> WaitHandle.WaitAny |> ignore
```

Note: I have not tried to compile or run this code.